# gmock: Returns distinct values on each mock invocation

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

Given:

```
struct MockThis : public IMocker {
    MOCK_METHOD0(ReturnThis, std::string());
};
```

I have an ON_CALL set up on this object so it returns a default value but suppose I want ReturnThis to return a different string for each invocation of it in my specific test, how do I accomplish that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider doing something like this:

```
struct MockThis : public IMocker {
    MOCK_METHOD0(ReturnThis, std::string());

    MockThis() {
        ON_CALL(*this, ReturnThis())
            .WillByDefault(Invoke(&real_, &MockThis ::ReturnStringVariations));
    }

protected:
    static std::string randomStrings[10];


    std::string ReturnStringVariations() {
        // Return some string on either random conditions, or calls counted, etc.
        unsigned int strIndex = std::rand() % 10;
        return randomStrings[strIndex];
    }
};

std::string MockThis::randomStrings[10] = {
    "Random string 1" ,
    // ...
    "Random string 10"
};
```

For generation of strings from a predefined array (as shown above), formatted variations, or whatever, you might consider using something from the [c++11 pseudo-random-numbers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) feature.